# Inventario de Arquivos

Tags: python, lista, windows, arquivo

Estou Aprendendo a programar e gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de criar no python um lista de inventario de arquivo de rede, contento as seguintes situações:
Caminho de Rede: \rg2srv0164\11_desenv_estrategico$
Após eu informar ele me retornar uma lista com o inventário como demostrador abaixo:

Pasta\subpastas | Data de Criação | Data de Modificação | Exemplo de arquivo | Autor do Arquivo | Salvo por|

e exportar em TXT ou CSV

inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

Comment: Existe diversas formas de fazer esse relatório, a mais fácil é utilizar o método walk() da biblioteca OS que vem no Python para listar todos arquivos da rede. Infelizmente não vou saber como obter a data de criação, modificação e autor desses arquivos mas e bem provável que exista uma biblioteca que cuide disso... Agora a parte de gerar o relatório a melhor opção é utilizar a biblioteca pandas, criar um dicionario contendo o nome dos index e passar uma lista com os arquivos, data, exemplos e autor. Criar um Dataframe com o dicionario e utilizar o método to_csv  para salvar em csv.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.